# Multiple Private Subs Worksheet_Change in same worhsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following sub in a worksheet, but I need another 3 of the same in the same worksheet for different cells/pivots. How can I do that?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
'B1 or B2 is touched
If Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Daily Overall").PivotTables("DailyOverallSignups")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Reg Year")
NewCat = Worksheets("Daily Overall").Range("B1").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Worksheet_Change or Worksheet_SelectionChange? Your title does not match your code. 2) You can have only one Worksheet_Change and without seeing the 'other three' you've alluded to it is impossible to help you stitch them together into a coherent package.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "the same" you mean that they all need to be in worksheet_selectionchange? Since your code currently exits if it isn't b1:b2, change your code to not exit at that point by adding other ranges. You should also have error handling and enableevents in there.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Bummer
    'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
    'B1 or B2 is touched
    If Not Intersect(target, Range("B1:B2")) Is Nothing Then 'if not nothing
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'Set the Variables to be used
        Dim pt As PivotTable
        Dim Field As PivotField
        Dim NewCat As String
        'Here you amend to suit your data
        Set pt = Worksheets("Daily Overall").PivotTables("DailyOverallSignups")
        Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Reg Year")
        NewCat = Worksheets("Daily Overall").Range("B1").Value
        'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
        With pt
            Field.ClearAllFilters
            Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
            pt.RefreshTable
        End With
    ElseIf Not Intersect(target, Range("c1:c2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MsgBox ("Foo")
    ElseIf Not Intersect(target, Range("d1:d2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MsgBox ("Bar")
    ElseIf Not Intersect(target, Range("e1:e2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MsgBox ("Hello World")
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

MovingOn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Bummer:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume MovingOn
End Sub
```